# ServiceStack.Redis search lists with entity property instead of ID

Tags: c#, entity-framework, servicestack.redis

I am trying to use Redis Cache for MVC application through Servicestack.Redis.

Redis only work with Key field (default Id). I have following classes

```
[DataContract]
public partial class Author_Book
{
    public Author_Book() { }
    public Author_Book(int id, string Title, int AuthorID)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Title = Title;
        this.AuthorId = AuthorID;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public partial class Author
{
    public Author()
    {
        this.Author_Book = new HashSet<Author_Book>();
    }

    public Author(int id, string name)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Author_Book = new HashSet<Author_Book>();
    }

    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<Author_Book> Author_Book { get; set; }
}
```

And following function to test

```
    public static void ListTest()
    {
        // configure Redis to use AuthorID as ID field for Author_Book entities
        ServiceStack.ModelConfig<Author_Book>.Id(x => x.AuthorId);

        PooledRedisClientManager redisManager = new PooledRedisClientManager("localhost:6379");

        Author auth = new Author(1, "Author-1");
        Author auth2 = new Author(2, "Author-2");

        Author_Book ab1 = new Author_Book(1, "Book-1", 1);
        Author_Book ab2 = new Author_Book(2, "Book-2", 2);
        Author_Book ab3 = new Author_Book(3, "Book-3", 2);

        IList<Author_Book> retList;

        using(IRedisClient rc = redisManager.GetClient())
        {
            // store Authors
            rc.Store<Author>(auth);
            rc.Store<Author>(auth2);

            // store Author Books
            rc.Store<Author_Book>(ab1);
            rc.Store<Author_Book>(ab2);
            rc.Store<Author_Book>(ab3);

            // Get data back from redis
            List<int> ids = new List<int>();
            ids.Add(2);
            retList = rc.GetByIds<Author_Book>(ids);
        }

        foreach(Author_Book ab in retList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ab.Title);
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
```

What i am trying to do here is,

1. instead of using Id, i configured `Redis` to use `AuthorID` as Key field for Author_Book entity.
2. Trying to get list of all books of Author.Id=2

The problem is, it is giving me only `Book-3`, expected result is `Book-2` and `Book-3`.

I guess `rc.Store<Author_Book>(ab3);` is overwriting the previous record as `ab2` and `ab3` both have same AuthorID.

How to achieve it?

I want to store separate lists of entities instead of Graph so later they can be updated/deleted individually.